# Firebase data insertion using child unique id

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner in Android studio. I retrieved child key in android studio and now I want to insert one Column into this child without loosing existing data. I just want to insert data existing child.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you're looking for the `updateChildren` method, that allows you to update specific children under a path, without replacing the other children under that path.

If the object you want to add a new property too lives under `pathToObject`, you can add new values with:

```
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("newProperty1", "New value");
childUpdates.put("newProperty2", "New value");

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference(pathToObject);
ref.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

If you only want to add/set a single property under the original path, you can also do that with:

```
ref.child("newProperty1").setValue("New value");
```

For more on this, see the documentation on [updating specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).